# Adding two Columns SQL Server Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum

I just want to add two of my SQL Server Table Columns I have been using this query to do so:

```
  SELECT 
      sessionnumber, sessioncount, timespent,
      SUM(sessioncount+timespent) as cnt 
  into d3 
  from clusters
  order by sessionnumber
```

But the thing is it is giving me the error like:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'clusters.sessionnumber' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I have been trying my best to overcome this problem but I am unsuccessful! can anybody help me out thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an aggregate function like `SUM` (or also `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, `COUNT`), all the other columns in your list of columns in the `SELECT` must be in a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
 SELECT 
      sessionnumber, sessioncount, timespent,
      SUM(sessioncount+timespent) as cnt 
  INTO d3 
  FROM clusters
  GROUP BY
      sessionnumber, sessioncount, timespent
  ORDER BY 
      sessionnumber
```

So you're basically "grouping" your data by those three columns (`sessionnumber, sessioncount, timespent`), summing up the `sessioncount + timespent` values for each group, and then you're inserting these values into the new `d3` table

Comment: Where does it say anything about grouping? The question just says 'adding two columns'

Comment: @MikeW: if he's using a `SUM()`, I'm assuming he meant to be grouping, too.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `sum()`, which totals down a column. Try this:

```
 SELECT sessionnumber,sessioncount,timespent, (sessioncount+timespent) as cnt 
 into d3 
 from clusters
 order by sessionnumber
```